# Filter data using spark in R

Tags: r, sparklyr

I have a spark dataframe as below:

```
> head(marketdata_spark)
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 5]
# Database: spark_connection
AD_CC_CC AD_CC_CC_1 CL_CC_CC CL_CC_CC_1       Date
 <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>     <date>
 -380       -380    -1580      -1580 2018-02-05
   20         20     -280       -280 2018-02-06
 -700       -700    -1730      -1730 2018-02-07
 -460       -460    -1100      -1100 2018-02-08
  260        260    -1780      -1780 2018-02-09
  480        480      380        380 2018-02-12
```

I would like filter the value as below but I am getting the following error:

```
marketdata_spark %>% filter(AD_CC_CC > 10.0)
```

> Error in storage.mode(x) <- "double" : 
>       (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

I tried converting the column to integer but still gave me the same error. Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: You've imported some package that shades `dplyr::filter` - otherwise it should work fine. Check for example `help(filter)` to see what variants are attached.

Comment: @user8371915 I believe this was indeed the case. I ran the same code after 2-3 days and it worked perfectly as was required.

Comment: For me it is shaded by `stats::filter`, which is never loaded explicitly (`stats` is loaded by default). Strange.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I want to add that what Alper t. Turker says in the comments was indeed true for me.

Before, I was only loading `sparklyr`, like so:

```
library(sparklyr)
```

What resolved my problem was loading both `sparklyr` *and then* `dplyr`:

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
```

If loaded in this order the dplyr::filter will mask the sparklyr::filter, which could not handle filter operations on columns.

Answer (score -3):

It works perfectly here

```
lines = 'AD_CC_CC AD_CC_CC_1 CL_CC_CC CL_CC_CC_1     Date
          -380       -380    -1580      -1580     2018-02-05
            20         20     -280       -280     2018-02-06
          -700       -700    -1730      -1730     2018-02-07
          -460       -460    -1100      -1100     2018-02-08
           260        260    -1780      -1780     2018-02-09
           480        480      380        380     2018-02-12'

marketdata_spark = read.table(textConnection(lines),header = T)

str(marketdata_spark)
#'data.frame':  6 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ AD_CC_CC  : int  -380 20 -700 -460 260 480
# $ AD_CC_CC_1: int  -380 20 -700 -460 260 480
# $ CL_CC_CC  : int  -1580 -280 -1730 -1100 -1780 380
# $ CL_CC_CC_1: int  -1580 -280 -1730 -1100 -1780 380
# $ Date      : Factor w/ 6 levels "2018-02-05","2018-02-06",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6

library(dplyr)
marketdata_spark %>% filter(AD_CC_CC > 10.0)
  AD_CC_CC AD_CC_CC_1 CL_CC_CC CL_CC_CC_1       Date
#1       20         20     -280       -280 2018-02-06
#2      260        260    -1780      -1780 2018-02-09
#3      480        480      380        380 2018-02-12
```

Another alternative would be to use this:

```
marketdata_spark[marketdata_spark$AD_CC_CC > 10.0,]
```

Comment: I think the solution you have provided works with R data frame and not Spark data frame. I tried the alternative solution and it gave me the following error: Error in marketdata_spark[marketdata_spark$AD_CC_CC > 10, ] : 
  incorrect number of dimensions